# Trying to send JSON data to a server, but getting an "unexpected end of string"

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am trying to send the data to server but getting the response null as server connect successfully

**it's showing an folowing error:-**

```
    "-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
         "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 
          \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x4b156c0 
          {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"
    )"
```

**My code is:--**

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{
                   \"userDetails\":[{
                                    \"username\":\"srj.s%2540xxxxxx.com\" ,
                                    \"password\":\"admin123\",
                                    \"apply_class_id\":\"\"}],
                   \"wsfunction\":\"user_authentication\"}@"];

//Encode the post string using NSASCIIStringEncoding and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.    
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

//send actual length of your data   
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

//Create URLRequest object and initialize it.   
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];


//Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request.    
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com:8080/xxxxxxxx.php"]]];

//set HTTP method (POST or GET).    
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Set HTTP header field with length of the post data.
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//Also set the Encoded value for HTTP header Field.
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"]; 

//Set the HTTPBody of the urlrequest with postData. 
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

//4. Now, create URLConnection object. Initialize it with the URLRequest.   
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

//check that whether you URL connection is done properly or not using just if/else statement as below       
 if(conn)
 {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
 }
 else
 {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
 }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    //While receiving the response data
    responseData = [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //When failed just log
    //[delegate hideIndicator];
    NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //When the response data is downloaded 
    // NSLog(@" Data obtained %@", responseData);
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // NSLog(@" Response String %@", responseString);
    //converted response json string to a simple NSdictionary
    
    NSMutableArray *results = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", results);
}
```

Comment: Please post your received response from the server.

Comment: `NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{` -- ***Why?*** Why `stringWithFormat:` if you have a constant string literal only?

Answer (score 0):

In your *post variable,

there is an unnecessary @ symbol at the end of the symbol, try removing this and execute your code.

Also for username you have % symbol, hope that would not mess up...

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"userDetails\":[{\"username\":\"srj.s%2540xxxxxx.com\" , \"password\":\"admin123\",\"apply_class_id\":\"\"}],\"wsfunction\":\"user_authentication\"}"];
```